# How long does each research project take to complete?

Tags: simcity-2013

In SimCity, there are a variety of research projects, many of which unlock the great work for your region. I am currently working on the Solar Farm Great Work;

[image]

How long does each research project take to complete? Is it a set time for each research project and if so does each research project take the same amount of time to complete? Are there any other factors that influence how long it takes for each research project to complete?

Comment: I do not have any numbers so I can not answer, but just a comment to say that the number of 'students' does seem to affect this.. In any case the timelines are Very long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every student seems to "unload" some of his knowledge into the project. You can observe that every time a class starts and all the students flow into the building, the percentage of completeness rises.

Also it seems that the projects have various required amounts corresponding to the complexity of the project. The advanced solar panels seemed to take much less time than the nuclear reactor.

Answer (score 3):

Just did some day-to-day testing about research time in SimCity. If only SimCity would tell us more information about length of projects, or what is happening, but once again it's up to the community to figure it out. The research project time is indeed based on the amount of students attending. And yes, different research goes at different speeds. Here's what I found:

Clean Coal Generator:

[image: Clean Coal]
[image: Clean Coal]

6% completed from 722 students. **0.83% researched per 100 students in one game-time day.** So if you averaged 1000 students per day you would get 8.3% completed every day. Or around 12 game days to complete it.

Clean Oil Generator:

[image: Clean Oil][image: Clean Oil]

10% completed from 1000 students. **1% researched per 100 students in one game-time day.** 10-12 days for Clean Coal/Oil with 1000 students.

Concentrated Solar Array:

[image: Concentrated Solar Array]
[image: Concentrated Solar Array]

11% for 1476 students or **0.74% researched per 100 students in one game-time day**. Or something like 13 days to complete.

Solar Farm Great Work:

[image: Solar Farm Great Work][image: Solar Farm Great Work]

9% for 1841 students or **0.48% researched per 100 students in one game-time day**. Or something like 20-21 days to complete.

I'm not very convinced at the reliability of these "students taught today" numbers but it seems **with 1000 students it would take 10-13 days** for the non-great work projects and 20 days for the great work projects.